# How to get the currency symbol for current user in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, globalization

Microsoft recommends using Windows.Globalization rather than System.Globalization for UWP apps ([Use global-ready formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/globalizing/use-global-ready-formats)).

Under Windows.Globalization.NumberFormatting Namespace there is a [CurrencyFormatter Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.globalization.numberformatting.currencyformatter) but I do not want to format a number as currency. I want to find how to get the currency symbol only.

What is current best practice for returning the currency symbol for the current user in UWP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`NumberFormatInfo.CurrencySymbol`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.currencysymbol(v=vs.110).aspx) property for that:

```
string currencySymbol = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencySymbol;
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no direct property to get that, but you can use this small trick:

```csharp
var currencyInUse = new Windows.Globalization.GeographicRegion().CurrenciesInUse[0];
var currencyFormatter = new Windows.Globalization.NumberFormatting.CurrencyFormatter(currencyInUse) { IsDecimalPointAlwaysDisplayed = false, FractionDigits = 0 };
var currencySymbol = currencyFormatter.Format(0).Replace("0", "");
```