# Check user currency symbol in UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-store-apps, globalization

We have a UWP app that offers in-app purchases. We need to ensure the user device uses the same currency symbol as the Microsoft Store for their region.

We seem to be able to deal with Euro for users in Ireland, but we have a problem with Germany and possibly other non-English speaking regions.

A user in Germany has their region set to Germany, their display language set to German, their currency symbol set to Euro. I have replicated these settings on my own machine.

On that machine and on my machine
`RegionInfo.CurrentRegion.CurrencySymbol` returns $, not Euro
`CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol` returns $, not Euro
`NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo.CurrencySymbol` returns $, not Euro

I run the same code in a console app with my machine set to German and I get the correct results.

How do we correctly check the currency symbol in UWP for a machine that is setup to use Euro in Germany?

Comment: I've edited the question to indicate this appears to be a UWP issue.

Comment: I just found a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42412937/how-to-get-the-currency-symbol-for-current-user-in-uwp) that appeared helpful (in terms of getting the currency symbol), but realised that it's also your question :D Oops!

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to create a `CultureInfoHelper` as shown at [CultureInfo changes in UWP - Part 2](https://www.pedrolamas.com/2017/05/03/cultureinfo-changes-in-uwp-part-2/)

Comment: Glad to see you found a solution! :)